# Not Disaply window tooltip in a href

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have created this tooltip 
[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/4787/)

```
<a href="#" title="This is some information for our tooltip." class="tooltip">CSS3 Tooltip</a>


.tooltip{
            display: inline;
            position: relative;
        }

        .tooltip:hover:after{
            background: #333;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
            border-radius: 5px;
            bottom: 26px;
            color: #fff;
            content: attr(title);
            left: 20%;
            padding: 5px 15px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 98;
            width: 220px;
        }

        .tooltip:hover:before{
            border: solid;
            border-color: #333 transparent;
            border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
            bottom: 20px;
            content: "";
            left: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 99;
        }
```

but along with the tooltip it displays a second small grey window with the same text. How can I get rid of the second window?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure the jsfiddle points to the correct fiddle? I see totally different code there. Please verify URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use title because title by default shows the yellow tooltip. Use html5 data attaribute instead.

```
<a href="#" data-tooltip="This is some information for our tooltip." class="tooltip">CSS3 Tooltip</a>



.tooltip:hover:after{
            background: #333;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
            border-radius: 5px;
            bottom: 26px;
            color: #fff;
            content: attr(data-tooltip); /* using data-tooltip */
            left: 20%;
            padding: 5px 15px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 98;
            width: 220px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The second box is the link title rendered by the browser. This is why many tooltip solutions use the new "data" attributes to store the text for the tooltip and the title is left blank. Not really recommended because the title attribute is used for accessibility.

You could also use javascript to remove the title attribute. Use javascript to capture the title, remove it, then feed it into your tooltip function. This would work.